# Unsure why my app crashes when I use express router

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ll6knx7sFis&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9iJ_KkrkBZWZRHVwnzLIoUE&index=3&ab_channel=TheNetNinja) tutorial and at around 9:30, I have all the code down but it isn't working for me. I get this in my terminal when I try running the backend:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/routes/workouts'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\localadmin\Desktop\cpp-queens\backend\server.js  
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)   
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\localadmin\Desktop\cpp-queens\backend\server.js:4:23)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'C:\\Users\\localadmin\\Desktop\\cpp-queens\\backend\\server.js' ]
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

The weird thing is that when I remove the parts which use express router, then it works and doesn't crash (I commented the stuff and labelled the the things that make the app crash. Here is the server.js file:

```
require('dotenv').config()

const express =  require('express')
// const workoutRoutes = require('/routes/workouts') MAKES APP CRASH

// express app
const app = express()

// middleware
app.use(express.json())

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.path, req.method)
    next()
})

// routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({msg: 'Welcome to the app'})
})
// app.use('/api/workouts', workoutRoutes) MAKES APP CRASH

// listening to requests
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log('listening on port 4000, testing')
})

process.env
```

Here is the workouts.js file in my routes directory:

```
const express = require('express')

const router = express.Router()

// GET all workouts
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({msg: 'GET all workouts'})
})

// GET a single workout
router.get('/:id', (res, req) => {
    res.json({msg: 'GET a single workout'})
})

// POST all workouts
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({msg: 'GET all workouts'})
})

// DELETE a single workout
router.delete('/:id', (res, req) => {
    res.json({msg: 'DELETE a single workout'})
})

// UPDATE a single workout
router.patch('/:id', (res, req) => {
    res.json({msg: 'UPDATE a single workout'})
})
module.exports = router
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: `/routes/workouts` is an absolute path and refers to a directory like `C:\routes\workouts` on a Windows machine. Don't you mean a relative path `./routes/workouts` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an index.js file for your /routes/workouts folder? If not, try importing the workoutRoutes as

```
const workoutRoutes = require("./routes/workouts/workout.js")
```